# How to use Joomla.listItemTask in Custom Component

Tags: joomla-4.x, custom-component, task

Hi i need an example on how to implement a simple on / off toggler in a Joomla 4/5 Custom Component's list view.
I've tried the following code but i did not get any reaction in the model / idk how to forward it from controller:

The Project:
Basic structure of a listview of items and edit of items
Models are called "RegistrationsModel" and "RegistrationModel".

In the listview of RegistrationModels I've rendered the following (in development):

```
...
<td class="text-center">
   <?php
      $task = $item->payment_status == 1 ? 'setunpaid' : 'setpaid';
      $class = $item->payment_status == 1 ? 'fas fa-check-circle text-success' : 'fas fa-times-circle text-danger';
      $label = $item->payment_status == 0 ? 'SET_PAID' : 'SET_UNPAID';
      $action = Text::_($label);
      echo '<a href="#" onclick="return Joomla.listItemTask(\'cb' . $i . '\',\'' . 'registration.' . $task . '\')" title="' . $action . '">';
        echo '<i class="' . $class . ' fa-lg" title="' . Text::_($label) . '"></i>';
      echo '</a>';
   ?>
</td>
...
```

Controllers are called "RegistrationsController" (extends AdminController) and "RegistrationController" (extends FormController).
The RegistrationModel extends the AdminModel

In the model I've placed these methods:

```
...
public function setpaid(){
        error_log('setPaid called');
    }

    public function setunpaid(){
        error_log('setUnpaid called');
    }
...
```

My RegistrationController:

```
class RegistrationController extends FormController
{
    protected $view_list = 'registrations';
    protected $default_view = 'registration';

    public function setpaid($data = null)
    {
        error_log(print_r($data, true));
        error_log('setpaid in controller');
        return true;
    }

    public function setunpaid($data = null)
    {
        error_log(print_r($data, true));
        error_log('setunpaid in controller');
        return true;
    }
}
```

In the controller the log gets called, but:
How can i forward the call from the controller to the model / identify the item in the model? "$data" is empty / null in Controller...

And (maybe solved automatically) when clicking the icon the list view disapears and shows a blank view now.

Thanks for guiding me into the right direction

*** Edit: ***
Thanks to Sharky's answer below the Controller looks now like this:

```
public function setpaid()
    {
        $ids = (array) $this->input->get('cid', [], 'int');
        $this->setPaymentStatus($ids, 1);
    }

    public function setunpaid()
    {
        $ids = (array) $this->input->get('cid', [], 'int');
        $this->setPaymentStatus($ids, 0);
    }

    protected function setPaymentStatus($ids, $status)
    {
        $model = $this->getModel('Registration');
        $model->setPaymentStatus($ids, $status);
    }
```

And in the Model:

```
public function setPaymentStatus($arrayOfIds, $status): void
    {
        $db = $this->getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->update($db->quoteName('#__com_componentname_registrations'));
        $query->set($db->quoteName('payment_status') . ' = ' . $status);
        $query->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' IN (' . implode(',', $arrayOfIds) . ')');
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $db->execute();
    }
```

When clicking on the icon it sets the new value - but the page got reloaded and the table is then gone, what did I have to write to block this behavior / to reload the list with the filters still set?

***Edit 2:***
Ok got it now, I modified my setPayment Method in the Controller:

```
protected function setPaymentStatus($ids, $status)
    {
        $model = $this->getModel('Registration');
        $model->setPaymentStatus($ids, $status);

        // Force a re-rendering of the listview and keep filter and current page thanks to input
        $url = 'index.php?option=com_componentname&view=registrations';
        $this->setRedirect(Route::_($url, false));

    }
```

Thanks to the input Joomla keeps the filter / listposition so the redirect itself is enough now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller task methods in Joomla do not accept any arguments. They should read data from `Joomla\Input\Input` object. The key to read depends on your HTML markup. It is the name of the element with ID passed to `Joomla.listItemTask()`. In core components it's usually `cid`:

```
public function setpaid()
{
    $ids = (array) $this->input->get('cid', [], 'int');
    ...
}
```